# Android CardUI Library: Refresh content of card on onResume event of Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, onresume, notifydatasetchanged

I am using [CardUILib](https://github.com/Androguide/cardsui-for-android) for one of my projects and I must confess it's awesome but have been stuck at an issue. I want to update all stacked card content on onResume event of Fragment. I am not able to find a method to refresh those content when onResume gets called.

I was thinking if if there was any method like notifyDataSetChanged but was not able to find such method for CardsUiLib. Please help.

Githib Link:  https://github.com/Androguide/cardsui-for-android
Another refrence of Library: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/cardsui/

Answer (score 0):

Use the setData for the card option and trigger your UI changes from there. I dont know whether this is the best option but it is one option that will work.